# Read database and map values back to flowfile using apache-nifi

Tags: csv, apache-nifi

I am try to impletement following scenario.
I take two values from database table and map them to flowfile content and if there a match, then add a new column to flowfile with database content.

In my database, I have :

```
locationID|storeID|siteName
___________________________
121       |  3232 | Colombo1
342       |  34343| Colombo2
```

In my flowfile I have only `locationID` and `storeID`

```
locationID,storeID
121,3232
342,34343
```

I want to match them with database records and add a new column to flowfile as `siteName` with respective data.

So final result should be:

```
locationID,storeID,siteName
121,3232,Colombo1
342,34343,Colombo2
```

For doing this I have tried `QueryDatabaseTableRecord`, but dont understand how to do this mapping thing with this.

Or do I have to use an external script for doing this?

EDIT : I use TimeScaleDB(Postgresql) database

Comment: Which database do you use?

Comment: @BastienB sorry about my mistake. I have updated the question,

Comment: you can use this new service in NiFi 1.10.0: [SimpleDatabaseLookupService](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-lookup-services-nar/1.10.0/org.apache.nifi.lookup.db.SimpleDatabaseLookupService/index.html)

Comment: I think you can use ```QueryDatabaseTable```. For that, you have to setup a connection in your dataFlow configuration.
In the property "Additional WHERE clause", you can use your ```locationID``` and ```storeID``` like ```locationID LIKE {locationID} AND storeID LIKE {storeID}```

Comment: @BastienB Could you please provide a sample? I have tried, but output comes in binary format.

Comment: @BehrouzSeyedi I use `nifi-1.9.2`

Comment: Take a look at this [ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-2997) for read your binary result

Comment: @BastienB so I should use `EncodeAttribute` or `EncodeContent` to convert values?

Comment: It depends if your outpout is in an attribute or not. I think, it is in content.

Comment: @BastienB Sorry, I use `nifi-1.9.2`, it doesnt any of these two processors.

Comment: Ok so you can try to use ```ExecuteScript``` and translate the binary to UTF-8 or other encoding with a script. You can read [this documentation](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/ExecuteScript-Cookbook-part-1/ta-p/248922) for understand the syntax to communicate with a script to NiFi.

Answer (score 2):

You should extract `LocationID` and `storeID` and add them to flowFile attributes, then use `ExecuteGroovyScript` processor and add this script to `Script Body`:

```
flowFile = session.get()
if(!flowFile) return
def result = SQL.db.firstRow("SELECT siteName FROM TABLE WHERE locationID=$locationId AND storeID=$storeId")
if(result)
    flowFile.siteName = result[0]
else
    flowFile.siteName = 'NULL'
REL_SUCCESS << flowFile
```

[image: ExecuteGroovyScript Configuration]

This script gets `siteName` from database and adds it to flowFile attribute. You can use another processor to convert this attributes to CSV again.

Comment: I am getting following error **cannot infer the sql type to use for instance**